# how to create spring quartz like application?

Tags: java, spring

Hi i want to create an application that works like spring quartz i can use the spring quartz to do the same my native goal is to create job which may have more then one steps to be executed (trigerred) after that there may be depended jobs also and we shold give the functionality to skip the next execution of particular job.

can any one provide the guidance how the spring quartz actually works?
how to create such application in java using spring ?

thanx in advance.

Comment: Can't you just have a look at the documentation and source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everybody for spending your valuable time to reply me I got it work and i found following links very useful.

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/ 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html

Answer (score 0):

That all sounds like stuff you can do with spring/quartz and a queue to queue up your "steps" in.

Comment: i have thought to create java class having execute method. and call that execute method every time job is scheduled